# Entity Framework: One-to-one and one-to-many relationship between same tables

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-5

Im having indirection issues when trying to configure the Fluent API for a property that has a single one-to-one relationship as well as a one-to-many relationship with the same entity. For example:

```
public class Person
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int PrimaryNameId { get; set; }
   public NameInfo PrimaryName { get; set; } // one-to-one
   public IList<NameInfo> Names { get; set; } // one-to-many
}
public class NameInfo
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int PersonId { get; set; }
   public Person Person { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

I am trying to capture the relationship where a person can have many names but in most cases, I'm only interested in their "PrimaryName". **I would prefer to not have a hanging column on the NameInfo table for IsPrimary**. That column will end up being NULL/FALSE for >90% of records.

When I tried to manually configure Fluent API for this

```
**Configuration on Person Entity**

        builder.HasOne(c => c.PrimaryName)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<Person>(c => c.PrimaryNameId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.HasMany(c => c.Names)
            .WithOne(n => n.Person)
            .HasForeignKey(n => n.PersonId);
```

there seems to exist foreign index key constraints that point to each other such that seeding the database fails. In order to add a NameInfo, I need the PersonId - but in order to add a Person, I need an existing NameInfo Id (for the required PrimaryNameId -> Primary Name).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Relationally you have created a catch-22 which has nothing to do with EF. Table-wise you expect to have:

```
Person
PersonId [PK Not NULL]
PrimaryNameId [FK Not NULL]
```

and

```
Name
NameId [PK Not NULL]
PersonId [FK Not NULL]
```

Something has to give because you cannot insert one before the other.

The trouble with trying to de-normalize in this manner at an object level, to have "Names" and "PrimaryName" references is that by having a PrimaryNameId in your Person, there is no way to enforce that The Name record pointed by PrimaryName is actually associated to that Person.  IsPrimaryName isn't a very reliable option for the same reason, there is no way to enforce that two or more records don't end up with IsPrimaryName = True. You can only make assumptions as much and run data validation checks to guard against invalid combinations after the fact.

When it comes to 1-to-1 relationships, the reason for doing this should be to have a performance benefit. The data pulled out to a 1-to-1 should be infrequently required and/or expensive to retrieve. If a customer must have One set of name values, and can have additional names, then the proper solution would be:

```
public class Person
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   // ... additional name-specific fields.
   public virtual ICollection<AdditionalName> AdditionalNames { get; set; } // one-to-many
}
```

Required Name details are not expensive, and they would most likely be used/useful most of the time. There is no benefit in attempting to normalize them out to a NameInfo table simply because it is possible that a Person may have additional names. Rather than attempting to normalize down to a NameInfo table which serves two purposes (a required name, and optional additional names) I would recommend just creating an AdditionalName table for the optional additional names.

Comment: I think your solution hangs on the major assumption that `NameInfo` is trivially a string. `NameInfo` contains more than just a name. How would you approach this problem if the entities were Person has a type Pet that is FavoritePet with a list of ICollection<Pet> Pets that they own?

Comment: In such a scenario, not everyone would necessarily have a favourite pet so a null-able FK would be plausible and removes the Catch-22, though that does not forgo the assumption that nothing in the data model enforces the FavoritePetId points to that person. (My FavoritePetId could easily point to one of your pets.)  If you have something more significant than just a Name that you need to mark as Primary, then I would suggest adopting a "Rank" as a unique index along-side PersonId. The Preferred/Favourite is the lowest, or highest rank.

Comment: I made no assumption that Name only contained a string. My example clearly stated `//.. additional name specific fields'. My point is that it doesn't matter if there is 1 field or 20 fields, if fields are *required* for a customer in a 1-1 relationship it makes absolutely no difference if they are declared in the Customer table or an adjoining table. A customer requires these name fields, a customer can additionally have optional name fields (stored in a 1-many table)  You're the one raising a question about an impossible data scenario, and then adding a straw man to justify it.